# load function of jquery doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, jquery

```
$toolTip_inner.load('ajax/fetchUser_data.php',{ id: $tooltipText });
```

I am trying to load the content of the php file to `toolTip_inner` and passing the parameters..

The file fetchUser_data.php executes a mysql statement and retrieves, but before that it goes to this statement:

`if(  isset($_GET["id"]) )
   {`

and never goes to into the if condition, why is that?!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You already answered your own question**: the `if` statement in your PHP code is not being triggered, which automatically implies that `$_GET['id']` is not set.

The [jQuery documentation on `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is quite clear on this:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

Since you are supplying `id` as an object, it will be available in `$_POST`.

Comment: was I providing javascript/jason objects?

Comment: Yes. Everything between curly brackets is automatically evaluated as an object.